# Transferring open account records between customers

Tags: x++, axapta

My customer is wanting to consolidate all the of their retail sales in AX under one customer per country.

Currently a new customer is created for each sale unless the customer has previously made a purchase, in which case the customer is reused.  One requirement of the functionality being implemented for this is to merge open AR associated with one customer record to another customer.

Could this be handled with a payment journal?  If so, any suggestions on how the journal lines should be constructed?

Comment: is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to change the account number in `CustTrans` and `CustTransOpen` in a job.

Also consider if ledger dimensions need changes, if so much more is involved.

Comment: Nope, no ledger dimensions need to be changed, so I will take a look at this.  Didn't realize it would be that easy.  Thanks for the suggestion!